# (!) Unused external imports. 'reduce' imported from external module 'lodash' but never used

Tags: javascript, import, lodash, node-modules, rollupjs

I am using `rollup` to build my *library* and I have a dependency on `lodash`.

but when I run `rollup` to bundle my **code**, I get this warning.

```
(!) Unused external imports
reduce imported from external module 'lodash' but never used
```

A sample of my code is as follow:

```
import { reduce } from "lodash"

export function someutilityfunction(args) {
    return reduce(args,() => {
        // do somthing
    }, {}) // A generic use case of reduce function
}
```

the **bundled** *library* works fine.

I have even tried using

```
import * as _ from "lodash"
```

and `lodash-es` instead of `lodash`

but no **success**.

Here is my *rollup.config.js*

```
import resolve      from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import babel        from 'rollup-plugin-babel'
import filesize     from 'rollup-plugin-filesize'
import typescript   from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2'
import commonjs     from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs'
import uglify       from 'rollup-plugin-uglify'

let production = (process.env.NODE_ENV == "production")

export default {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: {
        file: 'lib/index.js',
        format: 'cjs',
        name: 'my-library',
        sourcemap: true
    },
    external: [
        'rxjs',
        'axios',
        'lodash'
    ],
    plugins: [
        resolve(),
        typescript({
            tsconfigOverride: {
                compilerOptions: {
                    declaration: true,
                    moduleResolution: "node",
                    allowSyntheticDefaultImports: true
                }
            },
            // verbosity: 3,
            clean: true,
            rollupCommonJSResolveHack: true,
            abortOnError: false,
            typescript: require('typescript'),
        }),
        commonjs(),   
        babel({
            exclude: 'node_modules/**'
        }),
        production && uglify(),
        filesize()
    ],
    watch: {
        include: 'src/**'
    }
  };
```

I have used *this* **rollup config** before and it has worked fine, until now.

Am I missing something?

*And I know the title of the question can be more generic. feel free to improve the post.*

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a known issue with the tree-shaking within Rollup and Lodash (also D3 has a similar problem):

https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/691

Comment: I thought of using `babel-plugin-lodash` but settled down to using `const { reduce } = require("lodash")`. @th3n3wguy